# python bin data and return bin midpoint (maybe using pandas.cut and qcut)

Tags: python, pandas, binning

Can I make pandas cut/qcut function to return with bin endpoint or bin midpoint instead of a string of bin label?

Currently

```
pd.cut(pd.Series(np.arange(11)), bins = 5)

0     (-0.01, 2]
1     (-0.01, 2]
2     (-0.01, 2]
3         (2, 4]
4         (2, 4]
5         (4, 6]
6         (4, 6]
7         (6, 8]
8         (6, 8]
9        (8, 10]
10       (8, 10]
dtype: category
```

with category / string values. What I want is

```
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
```

with numerical values representing edge or midpoint of the bin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that this is an old post but I will take the liberty to answer it anyway.

It is **now** possible (ref @chrisb's answer) to access the endpoints for categorical intervals using `left` and `right`.

```
s = pd.cut(pd.Series(np.arange(11)), bins = 5)

mid = [(a.left + a.right)/2 for a in s]
Out[34]: [0.995, 0.995, 0.995, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0]
```

Since intervals are open to the left and closed to the right, the 'first' interval (the one starting at 0), actually starts at -0.01. To get a midpoint using 0 as the left value you can do this

```
mid_alt = [(a.left + a.right)/2 if a.left != -0.01 else a.right/2 for a in s]
Out[35]: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0]
```

Or, you can say that the intervals are closed to the left and open to the right

```
t = pd.cut(pd.Series(np.arange(11)), bins = 5, right=False)
Out[38]: 
0       [0.0, 2.0)
1       [0.0, 2.0)
2       [2.0, 4.0)
3       [2.0, 4.0)
4       [4.0, 6.0)
5       [4.0, 6.0)
6       [6.0, 8.0)
7       [6.0, 8.0)
8     [8.0, 10.01)
9     [8.0, 10.01)
10    [8.0, 10.01)
```

But, as you see, you get the same problem at the last interval.

Answer (score 13):

I noticed that a category has a `mid` property, so you can calculate the middle via an `apply`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({"val":np.arange(11)})
   ...: df["bins"] = pd.cut(df["val"], bins = 5)
   ...: df["bin_centres"] = df["bins"].apply(lambda x: x.mid)
   ...: df
Out[1]:
    val          bins bin_centres
0     0  (-0.01, 2.0]       0.995
1     1  (-0.01, 2.0]       0.995
2     2  (-0.01, 2.0]       0.995
3     3    (2.0, 4.0]       3.000
4     4    (2.0, 4.0]       3.000
5     5    (4.0, 6.0]       5.000
6     6    (4.0, 6.0]       5.000
7     7    (6.0, 8.0]       7.000
8     8    (6.0, 8.0]       7.000
9     9   (8.0, 10.0]       9.000
10   10   (8.0, 10.0]       9.000
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a work-in-progress [proposal](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8707) for an 'IntervalIndex' that would make this type of operation very straightforward.

But for now, you can get the bins by passing the `retbins` argument and calculate the midpoints.

```
In [8]: s, bins = pd.cut(pd.Series(np.arange(11)), bins = 5, retbins=True)

In [11]: mid = [(a + b) /2 for a,b in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]

In [13]: s.cat.rename_categories(mid)
Out[13]: 
0     0.995
1     0.995
2     0.995
3     3.000
4     3.000
5     5.000
6     5.000
7     7.000
8     7.000
9     9.000
10    9.000
dtype: category
Categories (5, float64): [0.995 < 3.000 < 5.000 < 7.000 < 9.000]
```