# pandas category column - why does .apply allow access to interval properties?

Tags: python, pandas

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689156/10595996), we can see that pd.cut() results in a column of type category and that .apply() allows access to the properties of a given interval value.

For example, this works:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.left)
```

But this does not work:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].left
```

I don't understand why this is. Couldn't find a good explanation. If someone can explain, that would be great.

Comment: Pandas serie does not have left method

Answer (score 0):

AmineBTG's comment on the question answers it.

In the following, .left applies to the series and there is no left method (or property) for pd.series

```
df['b'] = df['a'].left
```

In the following, .apply() works row-wise and acts on the series values one at a time. So .left is correctly interpreted as a property of each [interval] value.

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.left)
```